# How to create a custom admin form with multiselect type in magento 2?

Tags: adminform, magento2.3.3, multiselect

I created a custom module with a **multiselect** type input.

My **InstallSchema.php** file contains this for this field.

```
->addColumn(
    'elegible_products',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    500,
    ['nullable => false'],
    'Products'
)
```

My **Main.php** file looks like

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'elegible_products',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'label' => __('Products'),
        'title' => __('Products'),
        'name' => 'elegible_products',
        'values' => \Ayakil\FreeGift\Block\Adminhtml\Freegifts\Grid::getValueArray4(),
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

This is my **Grid.php** file

```
static public function getOptionArray4()
{
    $data_array = array(); 
    $data_array[0] = 'a1';
    $data_array[1] = 'a2';

    return($data_array);
}

static public function getValueArray4()
{
    $data_array = array();
    foreach(\Ayakil\FreeGift\Block\Adminhtml\Freegifts\Grid::getOptionArray4() as $k => $v) {
        $data_array[] = array('value' => $k, 'label' => $v);
    }

    return($data_array);
}
```

If i tried to save the form i am getting an error like below.

> {"0":"Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/muja/www/ayakil-greens/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3105","1"

How can add **Multiselect** in custom admin form and **save** the data and retrieve the data here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like in your save controller, you need to set multiselect's value as a string. For eg :

```
$data['elegible_products'] = implode(',',$data['elegible_products']);
```

And then, you need to save records.

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: thank you, This helped me.

Comment: welcome :) Happy coding !!

Comment: After this, I am facing a new issue when I try to see the saved values for multi-select. When I see the form, the selected values are not visible.